# How do I go back to the "microsoft agreement" page when downloading Unity Web Player?

Tags: unity, apt, wine

I tried to download Unity Web Player so I could play a couple of games on the web. However, when  I got to the "Microsoft agreement" part, I didn't know what to do and accidentally closed the konsole (terminal). How can I go back to it so I can agree to it and continue the process of downloading Unity Web Player? Am I supposed to delete what I did and restart? And if so, how do I do it?

This is what I did before getting to the agreement page;

```
    sudo apt-get-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
```

And this is where I messed up

Answer (score 0):

I believe running this command will automatically accept the license:

```
touch $HOME/.config/wine-wininet-installer.accept-license
```

---

If that doesn't work, proceed.

It's been a little while since I've used pipelight but I think this should work:

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --disable x64-unity3d
```

and/or

```
pipelight-plugin --disable x64-unity3d
```

then, enable it again:

```
pipelight-plugin --enable x64-unity3d
```

If that doesn't work, you can delete your pipelight prefix but I believe you will have to re-enable all the pipelight plugins again.

```
sudo rm -R ~/.wine-pipelight*
```